# Summing over function arguments in general situation

Tags: r

How are sums over arguments of a function performed in general case? I understand one can try workarounds in specific cases or use some loops, but there should be a general efficient way to perform this type of sums:

[image]

Comment: depending on the function you might be able to do smart things like matrix multiplies, etc., but a general solution in R uses `outer` as in `outer(1:10, 1:5, FUN=\`+\`)`

Comment: `sum(outer(...))` works indeed. Mathematica has specialized `Sum` function just to do the above, I thought it should be in R too.